# Pivot table in python pandas in specific format

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

Im a noob and would like to know how i can turn below table
[image]

into pivot using pivot_table in pandas to look like below table
i tried using below code but i cannot get it, can someone guide me:

```
df2=df.pivot_table(index=['Discipline','MR Cat','Field','Qty'],columns=['Currency'],values=['Price'],fill_value=0,aggfunc=sum)

print(df2.reset_index())
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please see [Ask] to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: i tried using pivot_Table and i cannot get to that specific format thats why im asking

Comment: do you mean `values=['Price']`, not `columns=['Price']`? also, pass `margins=True`  to `pivot_table` for the `Grand Total` row.

Comment: yes i corrected it should be values['Price'], but whenever i use columns=['Currency'] with values=['price'] Qty column disappers..i need  Qty column as per table above..any suggestions? thanks